# What is the word that is synonym to "right", and sounds like "rido"?

Tags: synonyms

There's a word that sounds similar to *rido* and means *right,* as in *correct*. I've heard it in a movie. What is it?

Comment: You mean 'right' as in the opposite of 'wrong' or opposite of 'left'? *Riba* [reeba] & *Louis*  [lewie] have been used as some obscure Cockney rhyming slang for 'right & 'left' before now. I have no source or citation, I've merely heard it used in conversation sporadically over the past 40 years or so. It's generally preceded by 'hang a' [riba/louis] & concluded with a location 'at the post office/just here' [etc] as an instruction whilst driving.

Comment: @Tetsujin in opposite of  `wrong` obviously.

Comment: @user218867  It isn't obvious at all.  Please edit that clarification into your question.

Comment: Shame on you to move this question here.

Comment: @gon You mean 'left' as the opposite of 'stayed' or the opposite of 'rido'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## [*Alrighty then!*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alrighty)

It doesn’t sound like "rido" — it sounds like "righto", because that’s what it is. Per the [paywalled OED entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/165899):

> ## righto
>
> **A.** *int*. *colloquial*. Expressing acknowledgement, assent, or compliance; ‘OK!’, ‘that's fine’, ‘agreed’. Cf. ***righty-ho*** *int*.

It means exactly the same thing *Right!* means. Their earliest citation is from Kipling:

> - **1893**   R. Kipling *Many Inventions* 374 
>     ‘What’s the matter? Hit?’ said Bai-Jove-Judson. ‘No, I’ve just seized of your roos-de-gare. Beg y’ pardon, sir.’ ‘Right O! Just the half a fraction of a point more.’ The wheel turned under the steady hand.

Notice that they reference *righty-ho*, which sounds like "righteo". That’s pretty common, too. Again, means the same ol’ thing by any other [nameo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(folk_song)).

Comment: Note that it's not "right-to", but "right-oh"

Comment: @HotLicks Rye-toe!

Comment: *"It doesn’t sound like "rido" — it sounds like "righto", because that’s what it is."* - It doesn't sound *like* "righto", it *is* "righto", which does in fact sound like  "rido" (or "ride-oh", which is what I assume the OP meant).

Comment: @nnnnnn: Some British seem to think that Americans pronounce *t* as *d*.

Comment: @GEdgar - Some Australians pronounce *t* as *d* 
when it appears in the middle of *some* words (e.g., *water*, or indeed *righto*), or pronounce it sort of halfway between *t* and *d*.

Comment: @nnnnnn The issue is that Brits and Americans will us a tap/flap as an intervocalic D, but Brits do not use it for intervocalic T in the way Americans, Canadians, and Australians do.

Comment: @nnnnnn And, with Canadian Raising, right-oh and ride-oh will have different I sound. So this will vary from region to region.

Comment: For those baffled by _roos-de-gare_: it is Kipling's rendering of the French expression [_ruse de guerre_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruse_de_guerre), deliberately misspelt to imply that it was mispronounced. As for _seized of_, I _think_ it means _realised_.

Comment: it's incredibly confusing to the new-to-English OP is "righty-ho" is mentioned. it is 1000% archaic.  the answer is simply "rightieo" or "righto".  (the enormous bold headline here "Alrighty then" has no connection at anything asked)

Comment: "Rido" doesn't sound like "right-o"? Do you live underwater? ;)